# Swift: iAd UITableViewController position

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, iad

I've created an iAd banner in the storyboard by dragging into the `UITableViewController`

In my `UITableViewController`, I have these codes

```
@IBOutlet var adBannerView: ADBannerView!
```

In `ViewDidLoad`

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
self.adBannerView.delegate = self
self.adBannerView.hidden = true
```

And these delegates method

```
func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    self.adBannerView.hidden = false
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("didFailToReceiveAdWithError")
    self.adBannerView.hidden = true
}
```

Sometimes when the UITableViewLoads, it would look like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4p1J.png

The iAd will be at the bottom of the TableView and it moves with it

However sometimes it would just load at the bottom of the View with a fixed position which is what i want.

How do i get the iAd to be fixed at the bottom and doesn't moves with the tableview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you are actually creating two `ADBannerView`'s here. Once in Interface Builder and another in your `viewDidLoad` with `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true`. Remove `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` from your `viewDidLoad` to correct this.

To pin your `ADBannerView` you created in Interface Builder to the bottom of your applications view you need to set its constraints. Pin your `ADBannerView` to the bottom of the view with `Bottom Space to: Bottom Layout Guide` and align it to `Align Center X to: Superview` in Interface Builder.

This will keep the `ADBannerView` on the bottom of your applications view and resize it appropriately when on devices with different screen dimensions.

Comment: Seems like constraints only works in UIViewController but not UITableViewController. The iAd is always at the same position

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to add any constraints in the storyboard. I removed the iAd banner from storyboard and just use:

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
```

Now it works fine

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem so I just coded my manually. Nothing worked when my code was in ViewDidLoad but instead ViewWillAppear all I needed was

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
    self.banner.delegate = self
}
```

And of course add the ADBannerViewDelegate at the top of the class then its methods:

```
let banner = ADBannerView(adType: .Banner)

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    self.view.addSubview(banner)
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    banner.removeFromSuperview()
}
```